# Echoing an SQL Field in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help with echoing an SQL field but it keeps showing Resource #4 or does not show anything at all.

My code is

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
session_register("myusername");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT statsight from playerinfo WHERE username = 'myusername'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(!session_is_registered('myusername')){
    header("location:mainlogin.php");
}

echo $row['statsight'];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        Login Successful
        <form name="form2" method="post" action="stat.php">
           Stat1: <?php echo "<td>".$row['statsight']."<td>"?>
           <input type="submit" value="+">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it does not show anything. It only shows `Stat1:` with the `+` button.

The value of `statsight` in the database is 3 if it matters, and the `myusername` information comes from a form.

Got it working using

```
session_start();
$myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
```

Comment: `session_register` and `session_is_registered` are deprecated, use the `$_SESSION` superglobal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
username = 'myusername'
```

you are not suing variable here.

I am no PHP expert, but this might be the proper way

```
mysql_query("SELECT statsight from playerinfo WHERE username = ' ". $myusername."'")            or die(mysql_error());
```

Although this is not a proper way, you should be using mechanism of Prepared statements while executing queries.

Comment: Correct. It can also be helpful to point out that this is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Or at least get the site url from the OP so you can pwn it later.

Comment: What are prepared statements? sorry i'm new to this. Do you mean stuff like ' ". $myusername."'?

Comment: @JordanGoh you can google 'Prepared Statement' and 'Sql Injection'. you will find very nice and handly articles on both the topics. Just to give you an idea Prepared Statements are used to set parameters in the query to avoid sql injection. and is a recommended way to do so. Is your problem solved using variable name in the query ?

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions agreed.

Comment: Nope. Because there is a login check page before this, so I think the problem is bringing forward the information from the login check page. And thanks for pointing out the error on my query. Also to prevent sql injection I just have to use stripslashes and mysql_real_escape_string right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` So that your field names are brought into the array as keys `$row['statsight']`

Comment: By default `mysql_fetch_array` fetches a row as both associative and numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put $ in here '$myusername'

$result = mysql_query("SELECT statsight from playerinfo WHERE username = '$myusername'")            or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

The mysql extension is not recommended anymore. We are meant to use mysqli instead now. While mysqli does support prepared statements, they are not necessary for a simple select like yours. Using the PHP function mysqli_real_escape_string() should be adequate. For an insert query, additional security is required.

The method you are using for sessions is completely deprecated. The proper method is shown in my sample code. I think your reference is so out of date that it is the source of your troubles. I recommend spending some time with a current copy of the official PHP manual.

There are several functions which can be used to handle results of a query which returns a resultset. Here is a partial listing of the

```
mixed mysqli_result::fetch_array ( [ int $resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH ] ) 
// allows you to retrieve an array with numeric keys, an associative array or both
array mysqli_result::fetch_assoc ( void )
// returns an associative array of the current row
object mysqli_result::fetch_object ([ string $class_name [, array $params ]] )
// returns the current row as an object
```

Mysqli can be used in an object oriented(OO) or procedural way. Most programs now use the OO style. Here is an example (in the OO style).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( $host, $username, $password, $dbname );
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    printf( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
    exit();
} 
$_SESSION[ 'myusername' ] = $_POST[ 'myusername' ]; 
$result = $mysqli->query
    ( "SELECT statsight from playerinfo WHERE username = '".
    $mysqli->real_escape_string('myusername' )."'";
$data_array = $result->fetch_assoc();  

//$result is a mysqli_result object. 
//$data_array is an array of field_name=>value pairs.

if( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'myusername' ])) header( "location:mainlogin.php" );

echo $data_array[ 'statsight' ];
$mysqli->close();
$result->free();
?>

<html>
<body>
    Login Successful
    <form name="form2" method="post" action="stat.php">
       Stat1: <?php echo "<td>".$data_array[ 'statsight' ]."<td>"?>
       <input type="submit" value="+">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this when I use your code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\loginsuccess.php on line 18, something is wrong with the fetching

Comment: @Jordan Goh Sorry. I left out a semi-colon after the query string, but I also think you should try to understand the code instead of just cutting amd pasting. give it a try now.